# Is it Necessary to De-Mean my Data before Applying PCA, or does pca(X) do that Automatically?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, pca

I am aware that a first step in performing PCA for dimensionality reduction is de-meaning the data.

I have performed PCA after de-meaning manually with X=X-mean(X) and compared with plainly applying [COEFF,score,latent,~,explained]=pca(X) on my data.

By inspecting the eigenvalues and the percentage of variability described by each PC on both cases (i.e. latent and explained in the above case), I can see that I get two different results. Is manual de-meaning doing too much in this case?

Comment: Did you use `pca` or `princomp`? Mathworks have replaced the former by the latter. In the documentation of princomp, one can read the following: `princomp centers X by subtracting off column means, but does not rescale the columns of X`.
Is this perhaps different from what you have done?